Replacing a string in a docx by a hyperlink using Python and the run concept while maintaining original font style and size
I have a Python script which aims to parse a docx Doc to replace codes (which may be unintentionally wrongly written) by text with a hyperlink. I already have the raw and cleaned values from the strings which were found in the document:
extracted_tv = [{'raw': 'TV-FRM-05496', 'cleaned': 'TV-FRM-05496'}, {'raw': 'TV-SOP-25663', 'cleaned': 'TV-SOP-25663'}, {'raw': 'TV--REF----66655', 'cleaned': 'TV-REF-66655'}, {'raw': 'TV-FRM-   054912', 'cleaned': 'TV-FRM-054912'}, {'raw': 'TVXFRM01496', 'cleaned': 'TV-XFRM-01496'}, {'raw': 'TV  WI  05496', 'cleaned': 'TV-WI-05496'}]

The docx contains the following:
TV-FRM-05496
ASDASTV-SOP-25663aS
TV--REF----66655
TV-FRM-054912
TV-XFRM-01496
TV-WI-05496
However, when executing the script below, all the strings above except by ¨TV--REF----66655¨ are being properly replaced by the hyperlink.
I tried removing the lower() function and playing around with joined runs. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong or any pointers? I have provided my attempt below.
import docx
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
from docx.enum.dml import MSO_THEME_COLOR_INDEX
import docx

def add_hyperlink(document, run, url, name):
"""
Add a hyperlink to a run while preserving the original font size and style,
but applying the hyperlink color and no underline.

    :param document: The Document being edited.
    :param run: The Run the hyperlink is being added to.
    :param url: The url to be added to the link.
    :param name: The text for the link to be displayed in the paragraph
    :return: None
    """
    
    # Preserve original font size and style
    font = run.font
    original_size = font.size
    original_bold = font.bold
    original_italic = font.italic
    original_name = font.name
    
    part = document.part
    rId = part.relate_to(url, docx.opc.constants.RELATIONSHIP_TYPE.HYPERLINK, is_external=True)
    
    # Create the hyperlink element
    hyperlink = OxmlElement('w:hyperlink')
    hyperlink.set(qn('r:id'), rId)
    hyperlink.set(qn('w:history'), '1')
    
    # Create a new run element
    new_run = OxmlElement('w:r')
    rPr = OxmlElement('w:rPr')
    
    # Set the hyperlink style
    rStyle = OxmlElement('w:rStyle')
    rStyle.set(qn('w:val'), 'Hyperlink')
    rPr.append(rStyle)
    
    # Apply the original font properties to the hyperlink
    if original_size:
        size = OxmlElement('w:sz')
        size.set(qn('w:val'), str(int(original_size.pt * 2)))  # Font size in half-points
        rPr.append(size)
    
    if original_bold:
        bold = OxmlElement('w:b')
        bold.set(qn('w:val'), 'true')
        rPr.append(bold)
    
    if original_italic:
        italic = OxmlElement('w:i')
        italic.set(qn('w:val'), 'true')
        rPr.append(italic)
    
    if original_name:
        rFonts = OxmlElement('w:rFonts')
        rFonts.set(qn('w:ascii'), original_name)
        rFonts.set(qn('w:hAnsi'), original_name)
        rPr.append(rFonts)
    
    # Apply the hyperlink color and remove underline
    color = OxmlElement('w:color')
    color.set(qn('w:val'), "0000FF")  # Blue color
    rPr.append(color)
    
    u = OxmlElement('w:u')
    u.set(qn('w:val'), 'none')  # Remove underline
    rPr.append(u)
    
    new_run.append(rPr)
    
    # Set the text for the new run
    new_run_text = OxmlElement('w:t')
    new_run_text.text = name
    new_run.append(new_run_text)
    
    # Append the new run to the hyperlink element
    hyperlink.append(new_run)
    
    # Insert the hyperlink before the original run and clear the original run
    run._r.addprevious(hyperlink)
    run.clear()
    
    return None

# Example usage

intermediate_docx_file = "intermediate_file.docx"
doc = docx.Document(intermediate_docx_file)

# Process paragraphs
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        for tv_item in extracted_tv:
            raw_tv_number = tv_item['raw']
            cleaned_tv_number = tv_item['cleaned']
            if raw_tv_number.lower() in run.text.lower():
              hyperlink_url = f'https://hyperlink.com/DocNum={cleaned_tv_number}'
              add_hyperlink(doc, run, hyperlink_url, cleaned_tv_number)
              run.text = run.text.replace(cleaned_tv_number, '')  # Remove the TV number from the run

output_docx_file = 'document_with_hyperlinks.docx'
doc.save(output_docx_file)


So, is the original text TV--REF----66655 in a single run or not? You seem to touch on this when you mention "playing around with joined runs" but I don't see that in your "Example usage" code.

If you are open to switching to a commercial library, you can consider using Aspose.Words to replace text in your document with hyperlinks. The idea is to replace the placeholder with itself to make it to be represented as a single Run, then locate the Run and insert a hyperlink. Here is a simple code that demonstrates the technique:
doc = aw.Document("C:\\Temp\\in.docx")
builder = aw.DocumentBuilder(doc)

# This is placeholder we would like to replace with hyperlink.
word = "test"
hyperlink = "https://www.aspose.com"

# Use Range.replace method to make each searched word a separate Run node.
opt = aw.replacing.FindReplaceOptions()
opt.use_substitutions = True
doc.range.replace(word, "$0", opt)

# Get all runs
runs = doc.get_child_nodes(aw.NodeType.RUN, True).to_array()

for r in runs :
    run = r.as_run()
    # process the runs with text that matches the searched word.
    if run.text == word:
        # Inset hyperlink
        builder.move_to(run)
        builder.insert_hyperlink(word, hyperlink, False)
        # remove the matched run, since we inserted hyperlink with the same text
        run.remove()

doc.save("C:\\Temp\\out.docx")

